# How to recompose a composable related to a screen resting in backstack navigation entry when parcelable in current screen changes?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

Imagine you have a screen that contains some addable items. Additionally, you can navigate to another screen by tapping into any addable item and the information in the item is passed by using parallelisation and navigation types. Finally, you have a button to add that item at the screen that we navigated. The two screens use different types of viewmodels and there are no repository layer exists. How can I notify the previous screen to recompose, or re-fetch the data by calling the API in order to show that item has been added?

There is a possible solution that creating a shared view model instance that keeps track of the passed object rather than using parcelization. But I am still curious about other possible solutions for that.

Comment: "re-fetch the data by calling the API" - that sounds like the job of a repository layer, which should be providing an observable Flow, etc. to your screens in the first place.

Comment: yes but think that the project is so huge that a repository layer can not be added :/ or will require a lot of refactoring

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why not use a callback? The only way other than using viewModels to communicate between two composables that I can think of is just passing a callback as a parameter.

Comment: @hahmraro is it possible to pass the callback between two viewModels?

Comment: Why would you want to have a callback between two viewModels? Just call some method of the viewModel inside the callback to inform it of the changes. You may want to add some code so we can help you out better.